# How to fix the vertical spacing of equations in align and gather environments?

Tags: equations, align, fontsize, gather, vertical-spacing

Here's a minimal LaTeX code showing my troubles:

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper,twoside]{book}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{amsmath}
%\setlength{\jot}{\baselineskip}

\begin{document}

Blabla:
    \begin{gather}
        x^2 - \frac{1}{2} \, x = 3, \\
        \frac{a^2}{b^3} \, y + 2 x \, y = y^2, \\
        a - b = c.      
    \end{gather}
Bla:
    \begin{gather}
        x^2 - \frac{1}{2} \, x = 3, \\[11pt]
        \frac{a^2}{b^3} \, y + 2 x \, y = y^2, \\[11pt]
        a - b = c.      
    \end{gather}
Blabla:
    \begin{gather}
        x^2 - \frac{1}{2} \, x = 3, \\[1ex]
        \frac{a^2}{b^3} \, y + 2 x \, y = y^2, \\[1ex]
        a - b = c.      
    \end{gather}

\end{document}
```

Here's a preview of what that code is doing.  I've shown in red what I dislike:

[image]

As you can see from the equation numbers on this preview, the vertical spacing is variable, and I hate that!  The global display is really ugly!!

I would like to define some small macros to replace `\\` and `\\[11pt]` and the likes to something that would adjust with the font size (`11pt` here), and that makes the vertical spacing between the equal sign to be the same.  I don't want LaTeX to make variable vertical spacings between equations.  Is that possible?

To solve the issue before, I was using some dirty hack:  **smash** all the offending fractions and summation signs in equations and use `\\[11pt]`, or `\\[22pt]` to adjust the spacing according to the equations.  Or I could add a **vphantom{\frac{}{}}** of some fraction to get something similar to the other equations.  This is certainly not a good way of doing things in LaTeX!

Comment: This is a good question. It taught me a problem I didn't know I had, but now I cannot unsee it and it does not let me sleep at night. I hope someone provides an answer.

Comment: If you dislike the fact that the `=` signs aren't aligned, you should be using `align` rather than `gather`.

Answer (score 2):

Using the medium-sized fractions from `nccmath` for fractional numeric coefficients (~80% of `\displaystyle` size), combined with `\addlinespace` from `booktabs` at the relevant places results in a spacing difference of only 1pt, which is acceptable:

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper,twoside]{book}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{nccmath, amsmath}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

    Blabla:
    \begin{gather}
        x^2 - \mfrac{1}{2} \, x = 3, \\
        \frac{a^2}{b^3} \, y + 2 x \, y = y^2, \\
    \addlinespace
        a - b = c.
    \end{gather}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is there another way?  This imply to use the commands depending on the equations to be displayed, a bit like the hack I was using before.  Is there a way to fix the vertical spacing by using something else than \\ ?

Comment: Also, the first fraction (1/2) is just an example here.  It could be a derivative or a fraction with symbols.  The spacing would then be different.

Comment: You can try the `spreadlines`  environment from `mathtools` which changes locally the value of `jot`. The spacings between the equation numbers won't be equal, but to the eye, it will be more acceptable. I think there can be no general solution, as it's a matter of appreciation from the eye, and two groups of equations will not have the same optical effect.  I any case, I recommend the use of `\mfrac` for numerical fractions, it will help.

Comment: For your other comment, yes, but the problem from the typographical -psychological point of view is different in my opinion: the reader tends to think that numerical coefficients do not have the same importance than fractions which could be formulæ on their own, and will find differences between spacings uglier in the first case than in the latter case.

Comment: So you say there's no way to fix the vertical spacing in the gather and align environments?

Comment: It is fixed by the value of `\jot`, but this does not make  the spacings equal if there is a difference in the heights of the formulæ in each line. It can only  make the difference acceptable to the eye (and the mind) of the reader.

Comment: In the preamble, what code line of jot would you recommend?

Comment: I don't think  it is sensible to do that for all multiline equations. It's better to do that locally for and equation or a group of equations for which it is necessary. That is what the spreadlines environment is for (it works somewhat like the subequations environment).